# Unable to pass query string with Header variable value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, query-string

In my .net application I created a label in my navigation bar that calls the header variable from the server as the username. This works fine but when I try to pass that variable to my other pages it doesn't work.

I decided the best option would be to use a querystring instead of session variables. So here is my code (disclaimer: first time using querystrings so not sure if it is used correctly or not)

aspx - Main page w/ username:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Username" Text="User"></asp:Label>
```

cs - Main page:

```
Username.Text = Request.Headers["displayname"];
Response.Redirect("About.aspx?Parameter=" + Username.Text);
```

aspx - About page needs/username:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Username" Text="User"></asp:Label>
```

cs - About page:

```
Username.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString();
```

I know some of this is probably wrong so any suggestions on the best way to do this or what I am doing wrong would really help me fix this problem.

**EDIT - added my cs from both pages**

Main:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Username.Text = Request.Headers["displayname"];
            DateUpdated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yy");
            Session["name"] = "Username.Text";
        }
```

About:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Username.Text = (string) (Session["Username"]);
            DateUpdated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yy");
        }
```

Comment: I would consider saving the user name as a session var instead of q string

Comment: Change your Session["UserName"] = "UserName"; to Session["UserName"] = UserName.Text;  I was using "UserName" as a placeholder.  Although, the way you are doing it should have set "UserName" (the literal string) to your label.

Comment: You also might want to put both of the code blocks in a if (!IsPostBack) block to ensure they only fire once (when the page loads initially, not in any subsequent post backs) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The more I look at this, the more confused I am.  Why are you using header vars?  Why not just set the UserName session variable whenever the user logs in?

Comment: sorry a little confused by your question, but I have to call the header variable to get it from the server (so I was told) I don't know of any other way to display it

Comment: Updated based on your code samples - see how session vars are being saved/retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session instead,

Save to session: `Session["UserName"] = "MyUserName" (wherever you're getting it)`
You'll probably want to do this wherever the user is logging in.

Retrieve/Set it to your label : `Username.Text = (string)(Session["UserName"]);`

This way you have access to it wherever you need it and someone can't simply manually change the query string to impersonate another user.

In order to use session, you must enable it using the session state node in web.config, the in-process mode will probably suit your needs the best.  Put the following node in the `<system.web>` node of your web.config:

```
<sessionstate 
      mode="inproc"
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20" 
/>
```

Edit based on your code samples, see how I am setting the "UserName" session var and retrieving it later:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
               Username.Text = Request.Headers["displayname"];
               DateUpdated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yy");
               Session["Username"] = Request.Headers["displayname"];
            }
        }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            if (!IsPostBack) {
               Username.Text = (string) (Session["Username"]);
               DateUpdated.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yy");
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but my variable still isn't being passed to my next page.

Comment: See my edit about allowing session state in web config.  If that is set and it still isn't working, are you sure you are adding the value to the session object?  If it's being added to session, it should be available anywhere in the app for that user.

Comment: get the error that sessionstate is invalid element in system.web

Comment: That's ok - Honestly, I'm not even sure it has to be there to use session vars, but I always add it.  Make sure you aren't overriding session in the <@% Page> directive at the top of the page with a EnableSessionState="false"

Comment: I think it should be sessionState with an upper case S for state

Comment: If you're sure you're adding it to session correctly, where in the page cycle of the About page are you setting it to the UserName.Text?  In the (!IsPostBack) section of Page_Load?  It might be easier if you copy/paste the entire code blocks from the Main page and About page (code behind)

Comment: @IniTech, I added both code blocks. I use Page_Load for both.